# nested serializer does not save nested fields

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

only the top-level table registers;

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class FormularModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    created_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        db_column="creation_date",
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'my_data_base'
        db_table = "formular"


class QuestionModel(models.Model):
    formular = models.OneToOneField(FormularModel, related_name='formular', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    field_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    update_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(
        db_column="my_data_base",
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'my_data_base'
        db_table = "question"

class ResponseModel(models.Model):
    question = models.OneToOneField(QuestionModel, related_name='question', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    values = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    update_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(
        db_column="update_date",
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'my_data_base'
        db_table = "response"

class FieldcontentModel(models.Model):
    questions = models.OneToOneField(QuestionModel, related_name='questions', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    values = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    place = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    
    update_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(
        db_column="update_date",
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'my_data_base'
        db_table = "field"
```

**serilizers.py**

```
from .models import *
from rest_framework import serializers
from drf_writable_nested.serializers import WritableNestedModelSerializer



class ResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta():
        model = ResponseModel
        fields = ['id', 'values']


class FieldSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    values = serializers.CharField()
    place = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta():
        model = FieldcontentModel
        fields = ['id', 'values', 'place']


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField()
    field_type = serializers.CharField()
    
    fieldcontent = FieldSerializer(many=True, allow_empty=False)
    response = ResponseSerializer(many=True, allow_empty=False)
    class Meta():
        model = QuestionModel
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'field_type', 'fieldcontent', 'response']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        fields_data = validated_data.pop('fieldcontent')
        responses_data = validated_data.pop('response')
        print('validated_data', validated_data)
        question = QuestionModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for field_data in fields_data:
            print('field_data;',field_data)
            FieldcontentModel.objects.create(question=question, **field_data,)
        if not responses_data:
            for response_data in responses_data:
                print('response_data;',response_data)
                ResponseModel.objects.create(question=question, **response_data,)
        return question


class FormularSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # question = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    question = QuestionSerializer(many=True, allow_empty=False)
    class Meta():
        model = FormularModel
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'question']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        questions_data = validated_data.pop('question')
        formular = FormularModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for question_data in questions_data:
            print(question_data)
            QuestionModel.objects.create(formular=formular, **question_data,)
        return formular
```

**views.py**

```
def create(self, request):
        
    formularSerializer = FormularSerializer(data=request.data)

    # Serialization
    formularSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    # Get Datas from front 
    title = formularSerializer.validated_data["title"]

    # check if recormodel exist
    num = FormularModel.objects.all().filter(
        title = title,
        created_by = id).count()
    if num >= 1:
        return Response(
        {
         'message': 'already exit.',
         'status': 'warning',
       },
      status=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT)
            
     else:
         formularSerializer.save(created_by = id) 
         return Response(
         {
           'status': 'create',
           'code': status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
         },
         status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**console**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/exercice/views.py", line 93, in create
    formularSerializer.save(created_by = id)
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/exercice/serializers.py", line 63, in create
    QuestionModel.objects.create(formular=formular, **question_data,)
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 512, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 559, in __init__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: QuestionModel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fieldcontent'
```

**requierement**

djangorestframework==3.13.1

python3.10

here is what I send by post method
**
{
"title": "string5",
"question": [
{
"title": "string",
"field_type": "string",
"fieldcontent": [
{
"values": "string",
"place": 1
}
],
"response": [
{
"values": "string"
}
]
}
]
}
**

Only formular is save at my_data_base

if there is an easier way to do it with drf-writable-nested==0.7.0 tell me please
[I followed this documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**fieldcontent** not exists in model **QuestionModel**

when you want to use nested serializer for model it should contain the relation field as ForeignKey or ManyToMany, also you revers the relation in your serialzier

check Neseted Serializer model in [DjangoRestFramework doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#inspecting-relationships), because when you use OneToOne relation you should only pass field id as a value not nested data for example

Comment: Thank you for your response. So I don't want to store Fieldcontent in QuestionModel table but I want to store Question_ID in FieldcontentModel.
one QuestionModel has one FieldcontentModel. but a FieldcontentModel can belong to several QuestionModels